# Creating a Django Rest Api to Store Values

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a python parser who creates two python lists, first one contains some IDs and the second one contains ip:port information which corresponds to those ID's. I need to create a django rest api to send these values and store them. I tried to read django documentation but I still don't know what to do, where to start. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'I need to create a django rest api to send these values and store them'. Do you mean that you need to perform a GET request and POST request from the API?
Also, have you defined a model to store the values that you'll fetch from the API?

You can also refer to [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) in case you need an API.

Comment: @Mehak exactly, I just need to POST the existing values from 2 sets and be able to perform GET request to access those values, but I have no idea how to do it. First thing I do was to check DRF site but documentation seems too complex for what I need. I dont know how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not easy to answer, although I can show you the right direction.

Django uses the Model object to interact with database. Therefore you should create one model with two fields. The first one is ID (*although read the documentation carefully, Django can create the ID automatically for you*) and the second one should be a String (or really object of your choice) to store IP/Port information. For information about models, visit the following page: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/

To submit your information to Django back-end, POST request should be used. What is POST request is beyond the scope of this comment, so I will just expect that you know what it is. Open your urls.py file and make an endpoint for this particular request. More information can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/.

To create a form for user, Django offers great object called Form. You need to create one in the forms.py file. To give you an example:

```
from yourapp.models import YourModelObject
class InformationForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = YourModelObject
         fields = ('id', 'ipportField')
```

To read more about forms, check the following doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/